# Is it possible to retrieve the clients IP address during policy-based autosigning

Tags: puppet

I want to use policy-based autosigning. To make sure the request is valid I want to know from which IP address the client connected and asked for a certificate. If the CN and IP address matches my CMDB I want to autosign the request.

I read the docs but it seems the IP address is not provided. Are there any workarounds to get the IP address of the requesting client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read the docs but it seems the IP address is not provided.

That is more or less correct.  The docs detail [the interface and expectations for policy executables](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.3/ssl_autosign.html#policy-executable-api).  The certname is provided as a program argument, and the CSR, in PEM form, is provided on the program's standard input.  Nothing else is provided by Puppet, nor indeed available to Puppet, as requesting a certificate is normally the very first interaction between an agent and a master.

> Are there any workarounds to get the IP address of the requesting client?

If you use hostname as certname (the default), or otherwise have some way to obtain the hostname, then you can attempt a DNS lookup.  Or under some circumstances you might be able to obtain the information from a DHCP server, NIS server, or other, similar system.  Alternatively, you may be able to use a different property as certname, for which you can perform an appropriate lookup -- perhaps an asset number, for example.

Additionally, you should be able to get the client to include its IP number as a [certificate extension](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.3/config_file_oid_map.html#certificate-extensions), which the policy executable should then be able to extract from the CSR.  But note well that if the CSR is then signed, that particular IP is permanently included inside the resulting cert, whether or not you need it for any other purpose, and regardless of any subsequent IP number change.

Comment: Indeed, your workaround is correct. But in my case I want to verify the IP address for security reasons, to not sign someone else's server. I would like to make a DNS lookup for the provided certname and want to verify if the resolved IP address matches the IP address the client comes from. Hence, I would need the IP address to be trusted and hence be provided by the puppetserver.

Comment: @KlausDarilion, the information you're looking for is not available to policy executables.  Your best options are probably (1) manual certificate signing, and (2) generating and distributing certificates out of band.  But to the best of my knowledge, autosigning does not afford the level of identity verification you require.